# python pandas - generic ways to deal with commas in string to float conversion with astype()

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, decimal-point

is there a generic way to tell pandas to use a comma (",") as decimal separators for type conversion from string to float etc.?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    "col_str": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col_int": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "col_float": ["1,2", "3,2342", "97837,8277"],
    "col_float2": ["13,2", "3234,2342", "263,8277"],
    "col_date": [datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0, 3, 4).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 2, 2, 4, 5).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 3, 6, 8, 4).isoformat()
                 ]
}

conversion_dict = {
    "col_str": str,
    "col_int": int,
    "col_float": float,
    "col_float2": float,
    "col_date": "datetime64"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df.dtypes)
df = df.astype(conversion_dict, errors="ignore")
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

The above example returns object-columns for "col_float" and "col_float2" or throws an error is errors is set to "raise".

I would like to use the astype()-method directly without manually replacing commas with dots.
The datasource generally returns floats with commas as decimal separator because the locale is set to german.

Is there a generic way to tell pandas as type that commas in floats - or any other numeric data type with decimals - are ok and should be converted automatically?

PS: I can´t use read_csv where you can specify the separator directly, because it´s a database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which columns have the issue, or is figuring that out part of the problem? Most straight-forward might be to replace then convert: `pd.to_numeric(df['col_float'].str.replace(',', '.'))`. IMO the `pd.to_XXX` methods are better suited for type conversions

Comment: Hi @ALollz, figuring out which columns have this tissue is part of the problem in the real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the following workaround. This still might break in some cases but I did not find a way to tell pands astype() that a comma is ok. If someone has another solution with pandas only, please let me know:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "col_str": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col_int": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "col_float": ["1,2", "3,2342", "97837,8277"],
    "col_float2": ["13,2", "3234,2342", "263,8277"],
    "col_date": [datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0, 3, 4).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 2, 2, 4, 5).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 3, 6, 8, 4).isoformat()
                 ]
}

conversion_dict = {
    "col_str": str,
    "col_int": int,
    "col_float": float,
    "col_float2": float,
    "col_date": "datetime64"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
throw_error = True

try:
    df = df.astype(conversion_dict, errors="raise")
except ValueError as e:
    error_message = str(e).strip().upper()
    error_search = "COULD NOT CONVERT STRING TO FLOAT:"
    # compare error messages to only get the string to float error because pandas only throws ValueError´s which
    # are not datatype specific. This might be quite hacky because error messages could change.
    if error_message[:len(error_search)] == error_search:
        # convert everything else and ignore errors for the float columns
        df = df.astype(conversion_dict, errors="ignore")
        # go over the conversion dict
        for key, value in conversion_dict.items():
            # print(str(key) + ":" + str(value) + ":" + str(df[key].dtype))
            # only apply to convert-to-float-columns which are not already in the correct pandas type float64
            # if you don´t check for correctly classified types, .str.replace() throws an error
            if (value == float or value == "float") and df[key].dtype != "float64":
                # df[key].apply(locale.atof) or anythin locale related is plattform dependant and therefore bad
                # in my opinion
                # locale settings for atof
                # WINDOWS: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
                # UNIX: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
                df[key] = pd.to_numeric(df[key].str.replace(',', '.'))
    else:
        if throw_error:
            # or do whatever is best suited for your use case
            raise ValueError(str(e))
        else:
            df = df.astype(conversion_dict, errors="ignore")

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the `locale` library to solve this in a generic way with `apply()` and `locale.atof`. Just substitute with an appropriate locale. I used de_DE in this case, because they use the "," decimal.

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale="de_DE")


data = {
    "col_str": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col_int": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "col_float": ["1,2", "3,2342", "97837,8277"],
    "col_float2": ["13,2", "3234,2342", "263,8277"],
    "col_date": [datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0, 3, 4).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 2, 2, 4, 5).isoformat(),
                 datetime(2020, 8, 3, 6, 8, 4).isoformat()
                 ]
}

conversion_dict = {
    "col_str": str,
    "col_int": int,
    "col_float": str,
    "col_float2": str,
    "col_date": "datetime64"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df.dtypes)
df = df.astype(conversion_dict, errors="ignore")
df["col_float"] = df["col_float"].apply(locale.atof)
df["col_float2"] = df["col_float2"].apply(locale.atof)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
col_str       object
col_int       object
col_float     object
col_float2    object
col_date      object
dtype: object
col_str               object
col_int                int64
col_float            float64
col_float2           float64
col_date      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
  col_str  col_int   col_float  col_float2            col_date
0       a        1      1.2000     13.2000 2020-08-01 00:03:04
1       b        2      3.2342   3234.2342 2020-08-02 02:04:05
2       c        3  97837.8277    263.8277 2020-08-03 06:08:04
```

Comment: Thanks for your answert. Unfortunately this is not the generic solution i´m looking for because i have to explicitly name the columns and apply a different method than astype() to them. It would be great if astype would take the locale settings into account instead of just demanding that dot.

Comment: Also, please be aware that locale is plattform specific, which means above code won´t run on windows in my opinion.

**WINDOWS**: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
**UNIX**: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

This code snippet now prohibits your code from running cross plattform.

Comment: You could always add a check for commas in data for each column. Also, this does not make the code inoperable on other platforms; you can check if your running on Windows/Unix using `os.name` and determine an appropriate locale from there.